# Javascript - How to get the sum of a checkbox group

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sum

I'm trying to get the sum of my checkbox group (from database):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({

// SOME CODE HERE

$("#permisos01Div").append("<input type='checkbox' name='chk_permisos' 
       onClick='VerCostoPermiso()' value='"+data[i].costo+"' > " + 
                                                data[i].permiso + "<br>");

// SOME CODE HERE

});

function VerCostoPermiso(){
    var group = document.getElementById('chk_permisos');
    var sum = 0.00;
    for (var i=0; i<group.length; i++){
        if (group[i].checked == true){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(group[i].value); 
        }
    }
    alert(sum);
}

</script>
```

The result should be: Every time i check the box, alert the sum of the total cbs checked.

My code doesn't work, i really don't know where is the problem.

Thank you for answers

Comment: [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) returns a single element, you need [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dont have an ID assigned, but your using getElementById.  Try getElementsByName.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using jQuery, you also have a `name` attribute, not an ID:

```
var sum = 0;
$(":checkbox:checked[name=chk_permisos]").each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"chk_permisos" is the value of a name attribute and should be selected with documents.getElementsByName("chk_permisos"):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function VerCostoPermiso() {
            var group = document.getElementsByName("chk_permisos");
            var sum = 0.00;
            for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
                if (group[i].checked == true) {
                    sum = sum + parseFloat(group[i].value);
                }
            }
            alert(sum);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="permisos01Div">
        <input type='checkbox' name='chk_permisos' onClick='VerCostoPermiso()' value='1'>A1<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='chk_permisos' onClick='VerCostoPermiso()' value='10'>B10<br>
        <input type='checkbox' name='chk_permisos' onClick='VerCostoPermiso()' value='100'>C100<br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a checkbox with out a value sometimes it has the value of "on". When you put this through the parseFloat function you get an error. I would add a number check to the if statement.

```
    if (group[i].checked == true && group[i].value*0 == 0);
```